# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1148 The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am trying to upload complete CSV file in Laravel code looks like this

```php
public function testfastupload(Request $request)
{
    $file = Flag::where('imported','=','0')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->first();

    $file_path = Config::get('filesystems.disks.local.root').'/'.$file->file_name;

    $query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" . $file_path . "'
    INTO TABLE testdb
    (name,
    phone,
    dob,
    addresse,
    @created_at,
    @updated_at)
    SET created_at=NOW(),updated_at=null";

    DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec($query);
}
```

I am getting error as follows

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1148 The used
>   command is not allowed with this MySQL version

I have also installed

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

The error report looks like this

> at PDO->exec('LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/testUploadExcelApp/uploadExcel/storage/app/379ea12c68e382a438592b4da305a3c2.csv' INTO TABLE testdb (name, phone, dob, addresse, @created_at, @updated_at) SET created_at=NOW(),updated_at=null') in ExcelhandellerController.php line 113

Can any one help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `'options'    => [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE=>true],` to your connection in `config/database.php` . This will enable the  local infile option, which is off by default.

Comment: added after that getting this error `PDO::exec(): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE forbidden`